# Как сделать такую css маску

Tags: html, css, svg

Подскажите, как сверстать такую белую адаптивную маску. Пробовал через `svg` и `border`, но там возникают проблемы с %.

P.s. под маской я имею ввиду белый треугольник, который находится выше черной трапеции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: белая маска это белый текст в черной трапеции или это белый фон вокруг трапеции?

Comment: белый треугольник, который сверху

Comment: белый треугольник, который выше трапеции?

Comment: да, его имею ввиду

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Решение адаптивно, работает во всех браузерах**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 961 208" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
  <defs>
  <mask id="svgMask">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"  />  
  <path d="M0 103.1 0 1.4l959.9 0z" fill="black" />
  </mask>
  </defs>
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#svgMask)" />  
    <text x="350" y="150" font-size="24px" font-family="sans-serif" fill="white" >We provide you everything</text>
</svg>
```

Параметры, позиционирование текста настраиваются внутри svg и текст будет, также адаптивно подстраиваться под любое разрешение экрана, не нарушая вёрстку.

Answer (score 4):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #000 0, #000 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}

p {
  padding-bottom: 5vw;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, aliquid.</p>
</header>
```

Выглядит не идеально , но думаю цвета здесь под себя сделать вы сможете.